# PHP Ghost Process Timing

Tags: php, performance

I've got a list of functions I am timing so that I might try and optimize some code:

```
$totalTime = microtime(true);

$time = microtime(true);
// function 1 .05 seconds
$func_1_time = microtime(true) - $time;

$time = microtime(true);
// function 2 .05 seconds
$func_2_time = microtime(true) - $time;

$time = microtime(true);
// function 3 .05 seconds
$func_3_time = microtime(true) - $time;

$time = microtime(true);
// function 4 .05 seconds
$func_4_time = microtime(true) - $time;

$timeTotals = $func_1_time + $func_2_time + $func_3_time + $func_4_time;

$totalTime = microtime(true) - $totalTime;
```

This is giving me a result something like:

```
// timeTotals .2 as expected
// totalTime 2.3939 ???
```

I can't imagine running the microtime(true) function is adding all that time... could it be?  or is something happening in the background I am not aware of in between each function?

Comment: How are you outputting these two variables? Remember float format can end up coming out as scientific notation depending on how you're handling it. `$totalTime` could very well be `0.23939`. e.g. `echo $timeTotals` gives you `9.5367431640625E-7` and `echo $totalTime` gives you `7.1525573730469E-6`

Comment: @sjagr these are just examples of the actual output, however if I do the addition in my head (with and without adding up timeTotals) the totalTime is very different then the actual function times.

Comment: Seems to be [correct](http://ideone.com/dpQTCK) though

Comment: @DarkBee, in this instance yes, unfortunately the code I'm running wouldn't really translate well for an example.  But, the gist is the same, a different output for the actual timing functions compared to the overall return (vastly different, not just a few milliseconds)